# How to I setup default php-fpm service if I have two versions of php

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, systemctl

I am having two versions of PHP on an ubuntu server that is `8.1` and `7.4` I installed both `PHP-fpm` extensions and I have this in `/var/run/php`

`php7.4-fpm.pid  php7.4-fpm.sock  php8.1-fpm.pid  php8.1-fpm.sock  php-fpm.sock`

I expected that running `systemctl status php-fpm` without the PHP version number would be running the default version PHP. but the service is not even there. I get this message `Unit php-fpm.service could not be found.` How can I fix this issue? Is it even possible?

I also noticed that in `/etc/php/` I only have sub folders for versions.

Comment: So, check which service units you do have. `systemctl list-units -t service |grep php`.

Comment: I get this 
`php7.4-fpm.service    loaded active running The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager                                          
  
php8.1-fpm.service      loaded active running The PHP 8.1 FastCGI Process Manager`